# Job laravel não passa os dados do construtor para o handler

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6, fila

Ao despachar um job no Laravel 5.6, envio parâmetros para o mesmo. No construtor, os parâmetros são recebidos normalmente, contendo os dados enviados. Porém, ao executar o job com o `php artisan queue:work`, um dos parâmetros se mostra vazio no handler.

Código que despacha o job:

```
public function enviar($id) {
    $evento = Evento::find($id);
    $subscribers = ParticipantesEvento::join('users', 'participantes_eventos.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
               ->select('users.name', 'users.email')
               ->where('evento_id', '=', $evento->id)
               ->get();
    $certificate = Certificado::where('evento_id', '=', $evento->id)->first();

    dispatch(new SendCertificatesByEmail($subscribers, $evento, $certificate));

    return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Processando...');
}
```

Segue o código (simplificado) do job:

```
namespace App\Jobs;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;

class SendCertificatesByEmail implements ShouldQueue {

    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $subscribers, $events, $certificate;

    public function __construct($s, $e, $c) {
        $this->subscribers = $s;
        $this->evento      = $e;
        $this->certificate = $c;

        print_r($this->subscribers);   // Tem dados
        print_r($this->evento);        // Tem dados
        print_r($this->certificate);   // Tem dados
    }

    public function handle() {
        print_r($this->subscribers);    // VAZIO!!!
        print_r($this->evento);         // Tem dados
        print_r($this->certificate);    // Tem dados
    }
}
```

Na documentação do Laravel, é orientado a declarar as variáveis no job como "protected", como estou fazendo. Mesmo assim, já tentei usando elas como "public". Mesmo problema. Além do mais, apenas uma das variáveis "se torna" vazia no handler. Alguma dica??

Comment: André, coloca o código no qual chama esse job.

Comment: @AndréLins Editei

Comment: Ao imprimir a variável no construtor:
[{"name":"Andre Raubach","email":"teste.raubach@gmail.com"},{"name":"Testador","email":"teste.teste@teste.br"}]

. Ao imprimir no handler:
[]

Comment: Tenta pegar só um item no retorno do subscribers, pode ser q exista um problema com array.

Comment: Uma outra possibilidade é q se esteja guardando a referência dele.

Comment: Tenho um projeto que faz isso sem nenhum problema, estou tentando ver se consigo forçar esse erro de alguma maneira.

Comment: Já tentei pegar só um item tbm. Na hora de imprimir dentro do handler dá erro (pq o array ta vazio)

Comment: Resolvido! Consegui a solução por aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55582181/laravel-queue-data-not-being-passed-from-constructor-to-handler/55583573#55583573